# html encoding in ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

i have a text-area field in ROR, i trying to save some text but on submitting it is displaying some Ascii values. how can i make this textarea not to encode into html.

"the thrill of appearing â€œon TVâ€ motivates farmers; " it is saved like this on submit

i want this text to be " æ " saved as it is but is saving as" æ " because that is html's accii value, so how can i escape that?

Comment: Which string you want to save instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line just at the beginning of your file:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i want this text to be " &aelig; " saved as it is but is saving as" æ " because that is html's accii value, so how can i escape that? i tried with encoding but did't work. thanq